# Prototype inheritance is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

Since my JavaScript childhood I have read and followed that I should override the constructor in case of prototypical inheritance. But I am surprised to see that the following example outputs the same at console even if the overriding constructor statement is commented. Please enlighten.

```
function A() {
    console.info("A constructor");
}

function B() {
    console.info("B constructor");
}

B.prototype = A.prototype;
B.prototype.constructor = B; // Do we really need this statement?

console.info("cp 1");
var b = new B();
console.info("cp 2");
```

Comment: js adds field constructor on prototype automatically, but you can overwrite it. there are no major consequences when creating new object. If you call new(B) you are still calling B constructor on new object regardless the prototype.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Hey why did you delete your answer to this question? It was helpful and I was to refer to the answer and I was to accept the answer as the solution. Can you please repost it, if possible?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't spend much time in the discussion yesterday as I was busy. That's why I removed it.

Comment: @thefourtheye that's no problem.. Please repost the solution sometimes, if you already have it with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting to the constructor part, there is a problem in your code. You are making both `B.prototype` and `A.prototype` the same, by doing

```
B.prototype = A.prototype;
```

This means that, you cannot effectively identify the parent of the objects constructed by these functions. Try this

```
console.log(new B() instanceof A, new B() instanceof B);
// true true
```

This is expected, since `B` is created by `B` and `B` is created from `A`'s prototype. But

```
console.log(new A() instanceof A, new A() instanceof B);
// true true
```

Whaaat? How come an object of `A` is an instance of `B`? Because, since you made `B.prototype` also the same as `A.prototype`, when an object `A` tries to find out if its prototype (`A.prototype` is the prototype of an object created from `A`) exists anywhere in the prototype chain of `B`. Since `B.prototype` is the same as `A.prototype`, an object of `A` can be treated like an object of `B`.

The right way to do this is,

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

Now, you are making `B`'s prototype an object created with the prototype of `A`. So, it is not `A`'prototype, but an object created based on the prototype of `A`.

---

Now, what if we don't do

```
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Try printing the `constructor` property of an object created by `B`, without that line

```
console.log((new B()).constructor);
// [Function: A]
```

Since `B`'s prototype still has the constructor value copied from `A`'s `prototype`, it still refers the function `A`. That is why we replace it with the `B` function object.

Comment: Very well Explained.. Thanks.. but my curiosity is in understanding that We  have overridden B.prototype with some object which extends A.prototype. So now calling the B constructor (directly or for creating a new instance) should look for the constructor property on its prototype which actually is A's prototype constructor. And hence the A's constructor body should actually be getting executed. But it is not happening so... why :|

Comment: @DopedDude: Javascript inheritance doesn't inherit constructors. Only attributes (defined in the prototype). If you need B's constructor to call A's constructor you need to do it manually inside B's constructor.

Comment: @DopedDude When you call `B` as a constructor function (`new B()`), it will invoke `B` function only. But, the objects created by `B`'s prototype will have `constructor` property set as `A`.

Comment: @thefourtheye validate this assumption: doing "new B()" does the followings internally:

Comment: @DopedDude I think your comment is not complete.

Comment: @thefourtheye validate this assumption: doing "new B()" does the followings internally:
1. creates an empty object as {}
2. Assign the value of the constructor function's prototype property to the new object's prototype property (in this case B's prototype is assigned to this object)
3. Identifies the constructor function to be invoked which is prototype.constructor property of this new object (in this case this will be A's prototype)
4. Invoke the constructor function, passing the new object as the "this" reference
.
So that means the A's constructor should be invoked

Comment: @DopedDude Only your 3rd point is wrong. `prototype`'s `constructor` property will not be used in the object construction process at all.

Comment: @thefourtheye then where does it resolve or find the constructor to invoke at all

Comment: @DopedDude In `new B()`, `B` is the function to be used to construct an object. The constructed object's constructor property will be set to `B`.